# How can we increment variables declared in scriptlet inside javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, scriptlet

I want to display an element of the list, but I have a problem with the incrementation of list counter. it inrements only one time.

here is my function code in javascript

```
var element= document.getElementById("question");
        timeTotal =timeTotal -1;
        var nextQuestNumber = <%=k%>;
        var nbQuestion = <%=iter%>;
      if (timeTotal <= 0 && nextQuestNumber>0 && nextQuestNumber<nbQuestion)
      {
          timeTotal=<%=a%>;
         element.innerHTML = '<c:out value="<%=listQuestions.get(k).getQuestion()%>"/>';
         <%=k++%>;
      }

      setTimeout("listIter()", 1000);
```

`k` is the counter initialized to zero, `iter` is the list size, and `timeTotal`  is the variable decrimenting the total time (one minute).
So each minute i want to get the next element of list and display it.

So to load this function I did this:

```
<body onload="listIter()">
```

And to repeate this function each second i did this inside the function:

```
setTimeout("listIter()", 1000);
```

But unfortunately, this not work for me.
Could you help me on that please and tell m

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly.

Either pass the whole list to the client side code first then have `k` client side and read the proper item from the client side array, or use AJAX to read the proper item from the server.

In addition, you don't have any stop condition so your function will keep running endlessly which isn't a good practice. When you are finished, don't call the function again.

Answer (score 0):

The jsp expressions like `<% .. %>` or `<c:out .. />` are evaluated on server side while your javascript code runs on client side. You should check the javascript code in your browser to see what is rendered server side.

Answer (score 0):

Following issues in the program:

> setTimeout("listIter()", 1000);

to

> setTimeout(listIter, 1000);

and

> <%=k++%>;

to

> nextQuestNumber++;

and

> timeTotal=<%=a%>;
>
> receive it in some other varible in the program as it is getting reset in every run.